# Select value and display in a combobox if the datetimepicker value lies between two extreme dates in a table in database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox

I am creating an attendance management system in vb.net and using MS access as my database. I created a leave form in which the student on leave has a roll number and his details along with the from date and to date field.[image: This is the leaves table]

What I'm trying to do is to show all the roll numbers of students in the `ComboBox` on leave if the `DateTimePicker` value is in between the to date and from date, the command that I created as MS access query is selecting the from date and to date ie., extreme dates matching with the `DateTimePicker` value but not showing the values if date is between the to and from date.

[image: This is the attendance form and on leave combobox]

this is the code and query:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("Select roll_no From leaves Where semester= " + ComboBox3.SelectedItem + " and (from_date<= #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "# and to_date >= #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "#)", con)

    Dim da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
    da1.SelectCommand = cmd1
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    dt1.Clear()
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    ComboBox4.DataSource = dt1
    ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "roll_no"
    ComboBox4.ValueMember = "roll_no"
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Is there any modification in query through which I can get my desired results to get all the roll no if `DateTimePicker` value is between dates in database?

Comment: When you run this sql directly against the database does it give the result you're expecting? Also your example has David on leave 01/01 to 28/01 and you're reporting for 30/01, so I wouldn't expect him to show, and he's not on leave on the 30/01.

Comment: The problem is that it shows records on both 01/01 and 28/01 but not in the dates between them

Comment: Use `Parameters.Add()` to specify the dates, do not concatenate formatted strings. The same goes for `semester`. Specify the same [OleDbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype) used in the database (probably `Date` an `Integer` - you didn't use a string type for your dates, right?). -- Remember to include all 24 hours in the end-date.

Comment: Can you please elaborate by writing a code bro. Because I cannot understand what you are saying. Actually I'm a beginner in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably do want to wrap the code in a using block - that way if you have a error, it will STILL close the connection. Also, it means you don't have to close the connection - a using block ALWAYS will (so, this costs you ONLY one extra line of code, but it more robust - will not leave stray connections open.

Next up:

While everyone warns and suggests to try and avoid string concertation for reasons of SQL injection?

Actually, the BETTER case is that string concatenation is tricky, messy, and you have to remember to use quotes to surround strings, maybe "#" for dates, and for numbers no surrounding delimiters. And one tiny missing single quote or whatever, and your sql is now wrong. So, this is a BETTER case and reason to use parameters - to allow you to write code, and write code that is easer to fix, read, maintain, and even add more parameters to without complex string concatenations.

So, I would suggest this:

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "Select roll_no From leaves Where from_date >= @cboDate and to_date <= @cboDate " &
        "AND semester  = @Semester"

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cboDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Semester", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ComboBox3.SelectedValue

        conn.Open()

        ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "roll_no"
        ComboBox4.ValueMember = "roll_no"
        ComboBox4.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader

    End Using
End Using
```

And note how I dumped the need for a data adaptor - don't' need it.

And note how I dumped the need for a data table - don't' need it.

However, you do OH SO VERY often need a data table. So, since we humans do things over and over without thinking - memory muscle - then I would suggest that it is ok to create and fill a data table and shove that into the "on leave".

So since we "often" will need a data table, then for the sake of learning, then you could write it this way (so we now learn how to fill a data table).

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
    Dim strSQL As String =
    "Select roll_no From leaves Where from_date >= @cboDate and to_date <= @cboDate " &
    "AND semester  = @Semester"

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cboDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Semester", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ComboBox3.SelectedValue

        conn.Open()

        Dim dt1 As New DataTable
        dt1.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "roll_no"
        ComboBox4.ValueMember = "roll_no"
        ComboBox4.DataSource = dt1

    End Using
End Using
```

But, either way? Note how I did not have to remember, think about, worry about, and try to figure out the delimiters. Is that a " # " we need for dates, or is that a " '  " we need around the date?

Of course this code would be placed in the timepicker value changed event.

Comment: Sorry to say but this is not the answer to my question. This is a suggestion of yours to make my code look clean but clearly my problem is something else which I have already explained in the question

Comment: does not the query with the date range that limits to the start and end date work? I kind of thought that was the question unless I missed something else? That code and query should correctly ONLY pull rows from table leaves into that combo box based on the date value you select from the date picker text box.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, this query works only for extreme dates for example if a student is taking leave from 1 Jan to 28 Jan, it will show the roll no in combobox on 1 and 28 only not other dates

Comment: No, look close at the condition - from_date >= DatePicker and to_date <= DatePicker ---- You can see that any "range" will work. So, if I choose the 15th, then Jan 1 <= Jan 15 AND Jan 30 >= Jan 15. So yes, that query should work just fine.